# How to implement `+` operator without modifying the LHS argument in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

I am trying to learn how overloading operators works in C++. I managed to figure out how to implement the `+=` and `=` operators, but I am struggling with the `+` operator. The compiler tells me that the operator can only take one or two arguments. I can't seem to figure out how to properly return the result.

The objects I can take as arguments would be the LHS and RHS of the operator, but it seems to me that I have to create a third instance of the class somehow to store and return the result. I don't think the `+` operator is supposed to be modifying either the LHS or the RHS themselves.

Furthermore, creating a new instance within the method would not work, since that object would be removed after the method finishes.

**So how do I properly store the result in a fresh instance?**

This is what I tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>

class smallclass
{
public:
    smallclass();
    smallclass(int x);

    smallclass& operator+=(smallclass&y);
    smallclass& operator=(smallclass& y);
    smallclass& operator+(smallclass& y);
    int a;

};

smallclass::smallclass()
{

}

smallclass::smallclass(int x)
{
    this->a = x;
}


smallclass& smallclass::operator+=(smallclass&y)
{
    this->a += y.a;

    return *this;
}

smallclass& smallclass::operator=(smallclass& y)
{
    int value = y.a;
    this->a = value;
    return *this;
}


smallclass& smallclass::operator+(smallclass& y)
{
    int value = y.a;
    this->a += value;

    return *this;
}


int main()
{
    smallclass a = smallclass(5);
    smallclass b = smallclass(6);

    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.a << std::endl;
    // a = 5
    // b = 6

    a += b;

    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.a << std::endl;
    // a = 11
    // b = 6

    a = b;

    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.a << std::endl;
    // a = 6
    // b = 6

    smallclass c;

    c = a + b;

    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.a << std::endl;
    // a = 12 should be 6
    // b = 6
    // c = 12

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should probably flag `operator+` as `const` so you don't accidentally modify anything. Make a copy of your object, add to it, return that.

Comment: Your `operator=` fails to return a value, thus the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie woops, fixed I hope.

Comment: You don't need to implement the assignment operator, the compiler does it for you. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: `operator +` should be returning a brand new instance of `smallclass`, not the original instance or a reference. `return smallclass(*this) += y;`

Comment: `operator +` is easy if you already have `operator +=` and a copy constructor. (Though you will want to return by value rather than by reference.)

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `this->` syntax to access class methods or members.  The exception is to differentiate member names from parameter variable names (which can be resolved by using different names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning `*this` from `operator+`. You should instead return an object that contains the new result. By returning `*this` you are saying that the result of `x + y` is always `x`, which is not true. The result is a new value, distinct from both `x` and `y`. Notice that the return type should not be a reference, since the returned value doesn't refer to any existing instance.

```
smallclass smallclass::operator+(smallclass& y)
{
    smallclass result;
    result.a = this->a + y.a;
    return result;
}
```

You should also read about `const` correctness. By making `y` a `const` reference you guarantee the user that your operator will not modify `y`. The same is true about making the entire member function `const`. It guarantees to the user of your class that the operator won't modify `this`. Without these `const` you will not be able to use your operator with `const` instances.

```
smallclass smallclass::operator+(const smallclass& y) const
{
    smallclass result;
    result.a = this->a + y.a;
    return result;
}
```

A more idiomatic approach is to implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=` and of the copy constructor. That way, you don't have to repeat yourself.

```
smallclass smallclass::operator+(const smallclass& y) const
{
    smallclass result(*this);
    result += y;
    return result;
}
```

You can do this for many operators. Notably the comparison operators can be all be implemented in terms of only two fundamental comparisons, for example `operator==` and `operator<`.

Comment: An even shorter example: `return smallclass(*this) += y;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That would probably inhibit RVO.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical version of implementing `operator+` is this:

```
friend smallclass operator+ (smallclass op1, smallclass const& op2) {
   op1 += op2;
   return op1;
}
```

This approach leverages copy-elision where possible and also leveraged the existing implementation of `operator+=`.

If you want to inhibit auto conversion on the left hand side you can use the version below for a commutative addition:

```
smallclass operator+ (smallclass rhs) const {
    rhs += *this;
    return rhs;
}
```

If the addition is not commutative you’d use

```
smallclass operator+ (smallclass const& rhs) const {
    return smallclass(*this) += rhs;
}
```

(the last version can’t entirely elide one copy).

Comment: I would note this is canonical assuming you want auto conversion of the lhs from `int` to `smallclass`.  If not then a member method is more appropriate.

Comment: @LokiAstari: since you get auto conversion on the rhs and addition is commutative it seems consistent to have auto conversion on the lhs, too.

Comment: It "leverages copy elision where possible" except for NRVO. So if the LHS is an lvalue it could be less optimal than the version taking lvalue references and making a copy in the body of the function.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Don't disagree with that point. Just thought it was worth pointing out as the OP question does not have enough context.